# Automatically Open VF page upon lead conversion

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a VF page that sends a PDF to a contact on an opportunity which is accessed via clicking a 'Send PDF' button. Now this works fine but I would like this button to be clicked or rather the VF page should be open as soon as I convert a lead. Any ideas how I can do this?

I was thinking maybe a trigger on a lead that runs after update and somehow opens the page. Can someone advise me on how I can do this or provide me a sample on the opening the page part?

Please note, here is my VF Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="DealPDFGenerationController" action="{!generatePdf}">
<apex:pageblock >
    <apex:pageMessages />
    Please click <a href="/{!dealId}" >here</a> to return to the Deal
</apex:pageblock>
</apex:page>
```

The extension:

```
public with sharing class DealPDFGenerationController {
    public Id dealId {get;set;}
    public Opportunity deal {get;set;}


public DealPDFGenerationController(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
    dealId = controller.getRecord().id;
    deal= [Select Id,Name,Sales_Manager__c,StageName,Count__c,Sales_Manager__r.Email,Dealership_Allocated__c,AccountId,
            Variant__c, Model__c,Test_Drive_Completed__c,Sales_Executive__c,Regional_Manager__c,Owner.Email,
            Regional_Manager__r.Email
             from Opportunity where Id =:dealId];
}
public PageReference generatePdf(){

     PageReference pdf = Page.DealPDFTemplate;
    // add parent id to the parameters for standardcontroller
    pdf.getParameters().put('id',dealId);
    // create the new attachment
    Attachment attach = new Attachment();

    // the contents of the attachment from the pdf
    Blob body;

    try {

        // returns the output of the page as a PDF
        body = pdf.getContent();

    // need to pass unit test -- current bug    
    } catch (VisualforceException e) {
        body = Blob.valueOf('Some Text');
    }

    attach.Body = body;

    //Find the version no
    //Integer version = [Select count() from Dealer_Communication__c where Deal__c=: dealId];
   // version++;

    Decimal version=deal.Count__c+1;
    // add the Deal name + Version no
    attach.Name = deal.Name + 'V' + version + '.pdf';
    attach.IsPrivate = false;

    //Create a new dealer communication entry
    Dealer_Communication__c dc = new Dealer_Communication__c();
    dc.Name=deal.Name + 'V' + version + '.pdf';
    dc.Deal__c=dealId;
    dc.Dealership__c=deal.Dealership_Allocated__c;
    dc.Customer_Name__c=deal.AccountId;
    dc.Date_Sent__c=Date.today();
    dc.Model__c=deal.Model__c;
    dc.Variant__c=deal.Variant__c;
    dc.Sales_Manager__c=deal.Sales_Manager__c;
    dc.Test_Drive_Date__c=deal.Test_Drive_Completed__c;

    if(deal.Sales_Manager__r.Email==null)
        {ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Sales Manager doesnt have the Email field populated to send the mail'));
        return null;
        }
    // attach the pdf to the opportunity
    attach.ParentId = dealId;
     try {
        insert attach;
        insert dc;
     } catch (Exception e) {
       ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Error in saving the attachment'));
    }


     deal.StageName='PDF Sent';
     update deal;

       id templateId=[SELECT BrandTemplateId,Description,DeveloperName,HtmlValue,Id,IsActive,Name,TemplateStyle,TemplateType,TimesUsed FROM EmailTemplate where DeveloperName='Assigned_Dealership_VF'].id; 

    //Redirect user to standard email template page
    //edit email template if for PROD - 00Xb0000000emo9
    //edit email template if for Sandbox - 00Xg0000000R0mB
    PageReference ReturnPage = new PageReference('/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?rtype=003&p2_lkid='+deal.Sales_Executive__c+
                                '&p4='+deal.Sales_Manager__r.Email+','+deal.Regional_Manager__r.Email+'&p5='+deal.Owner.Email+'&p3_lkid='+dealId+'&retURL=%2F'+dealId+'&template_id='+templateId+'&new_template=1'); 
    return ReturnPage;

}
public void sendMail(Blob body){

    //Get the template Id
    EmailTemplate templateId = [Select id from EmailTemplate where name = 'Assigned Dealership'];

    //Attach the pdf to mail
    Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attach = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
    attach.setContentType('application/pdf');
    attach.setFileName('CustomerDetail');
    attach.setInline(false);
    attach.Body = body;


    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

    mail.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] { attach }); 
    mail.setTemplateID(templateId.Id); 
    mail.setTargetObjectId(deal.Sales_Manager__c); 
    // Send the email
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });

    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'Email with PDF sent  '));

}
}
```

Comment: You are using a vf page rendered as pdf or what. Where is this pdf stored?

Comment: @Nitin yes I am using a vf page rendered as pdf. Please find attached my code.

Comment: getContent is not allowed through triggers. But you can do one thing, call  "generatePdf" as the future method from your afterupdate trigger. You can also use process builder to call this "generatePdf". Does it makes sense?

Comment: @Nitin im not too sure what you mean here. How would I call it in the trigger and then what because the vf page is meant to replace the current page. Im not too sure what you mean :(